# How do I measure height above a surface whose boundary is defined as 3D points

Tags: 3d, geometry

I have a list of ordered 3D points which define the boundary of a surface.  Nothing else about the surface is known.  In theory these can be arbitrarily complex, however in practice there are a small number of points that mostly define flat planes with some ramps etc. Given an arbitrary point whose x and y coordinate are within the boundary, I want to know the height above the corresponding point on the surface that the boundary defines.

Comment: Should perhaps be moved to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the way the points define the surface and characteristics of points arrangement:
Do the points define a heightmap?
Do the points create regular grid or not?
Would you like to define the surface as set of polygons or an isosurface?

I try to guess that you have a regular heightmap.
I that case you need:

1. Define in what quad of the vertex regular grid the corresponding point is.
2. Break the quad into 2 triangles
3. Define in what triangle (XY-projection of the triangle) the corresponding point is.
4. Find an intersection of the quad and the vector(x, y, 1) where (x,y) - the corresponding point
   (google "point-triangle intersection")

Comment: The points are an irregular boundary, but they are almost always approximately rectangular. I think if we can work out the ends of the boundary and follow more or less this approach to create triangles between opposite points on the boundary, that will be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Treat your collection of points as a bunch of definitions for planes (Can you determine which points are part of an object?)

Define a line from your given point with a vector(a line) pointing "down".

Iterate through the planes and see if the vector intersects any of them. The distance between (x,y) and the intersection point is the "height"

Comment: To do this, for each point I would have find closest two neighbors and treat as a triangle?

Comment: If you can't determine which points define an object that's the only way I can think of. If you get points from two different objects you will end up with some extra planes and might get some false hits.